# Does improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\,dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus

I know that the function
$$y=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$
is symmetric to the origin point, so that I thought its improper integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ might converge to $0$. But it seems that it's not true. how is that possible?

Comment: It depends on how you define the improper integral. If you take the two limits separately then it diverges. But the Cauchy principal value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Cauchy_principal_value) is zero. (Note that the Cauchy principal value is not translation-invariant.)

Answer (score 2):

When we use $\infty$ alone in our formulation, we abuse the notation, and in order to be rigorous we need to use limit.

For instance, $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ means $\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_0^{T}f(x)dx$.

In your problem, you have two infinity so you need to write the integral with two limits:

$$ \lim_{T \to \infty}\int_0^{T}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx+\lim_{T' \to \infty}\int_{-T'}^{0}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx=\lim_{T \to \infty}\ln(T^2+1)-\lim_{T' \to \infty}\ln(T'^2+1)$$

Now, you cannot find the answer unless you know the relation between $T$ and $T'$.

For example, if $T'=T$ then your problem would be:

$$\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{-T}^{T}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx=0$$

If $T'=2T$ then

$$\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{-2T}^{T}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx=-\infty$$

If $T'=0.5T$ then

$$\lim_{T \to \infty}\int_{-0.5T}^{T}\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx=\infty$$